# How to Integrate Razorpay in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I'm using angular 2. I've tried below URL's to integrate Razorpay
[https://docs.razorpay.com/docs/checkout-form][1]

When i follow this URL, i got these errors like
In my '.ts' file code

```
var options = {
    "key": "YOUR_KEY_ID",
    "amount": "2000", // 2000 paise = INR 20
    "name": "Merchant Name",
    "description": "Purchase Description",
    "image": "/your_logo.png",
    "handler": function (response){
        alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
    },
    "prefill": {
        "name": "Harshil Mathur",
        "email": "harshil@razorpay.com"
    },
    "notes": {
        "address": "Hello World"
    },
    "theme": {
        "color": "#F37254"
    }
};
var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);

document.getElementById('rzp-button1').onclick = function(e){
    rzp1.open();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot Find name 'Razorpay' of undefined

Comment: try by declaring above the constructor like this `declare var Razorpay:any`

Comment: When i declare var Razorpay:any. I'm getting this error: 'TypeError: Razorpay is not a constructor'

Comment: Make sure that checkout.js is included before that line is executed.

Comment: In '.ts' file we can't access '.js' file so, 'checkout.js' included in html file.

Answer (score 14):

Ok am a little late to the party , but i was stuck in same problem.

`Razorpay` is undefined because its defined on window object, so you need something like `window.Razorpay`

And as @Pradeep said in comment declare var Razorpay:any , no this won't work either

And @Rajesh Keerthi `In '.ts' file we can't access '.js' file so, 'checkout.js' included in html file` you can't put script tags in angular 2 components html , because of sanitization ref [this](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-security-the-domsanitizer-service-2202c83bd90)

Now coming to solution, how to do it.
First put

```
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
```

at `index.html` 
Now you have Razorpay object on window , but how to access it in .ts file ?
Follow this [link](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/09/ng2-get-window-ref/) and create a `WindowRef` service and inject it in provider as article says, then in your 
MyComponent.ts file put

```
import { WindowRef } from './WindowRef';
@Component({...})
class MyComponent {

    constructor(private winRef: WindowRef) {
    }
    rzp1:any;
    options = {
       "key": "rzp_test_HTQz79bVMhpN4L",
       "amount": "2000",
       "name": "Merchant Name",
       ....
       .....
    };

    public initPay():void {
       this.rzp1 = new this.winRef.nativeWindow.Razorpay(this.options);
       this.rzp1.open();
    }
}
```

And MyComponent.html will have

```
<button id="rzp-button1" (click)="initPay();">Pay</button>
```

And Voila!! you have razorpay integrated

Even if you are trying out some other payment gateways like paytm or so, this approach will help

Comment: 'TypeError: Razorpay is not a constructor' stopped now but this is coming:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null at Y.postMessage (https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js:1:21748) at Y.onload (https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js:1:22025) at Y.openRzp (https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js:1:20523) at G (https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js:1:8414) at window.Razorpay.<anonymous> (https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js:1:24138) at window.Razorpay.e [as open] (https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js:1:3612)

Comment: @niravpatel9898 sorry tried that long back , don't have much context now

Comment: @AishwatSingh I am getting this issue , can anyone help me please
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null

Comment: @SaravananNandhan worked on this long back, sry mate

Comment: I followed your way , But I am getting error on using nativeWindow ,  Property 'nativeWindow' does not exist on type 'ICustomWindow'.ts(2339)

Comment: @TestingAnurag , that's defined in `WindowRef ` so check this import `import { WindowRef } from './WindowRef';` go in node_modules and see source of WindowRef, does it have `nativeWindow ` defined anywhere, might have been renamed in newer version or something, just something to start debugging

Comment: i am getting rzp.open() is not a function..please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: @nagenderpratapchauhan do you code in some repo i can take a look at?

Comment: I am not able to display, spinner, ng-template with dynamic text or successfully route to other component after razor pay completes its process.

Comment: in my case, i declared Razorpay name as RazorpayCheckout which failed, RazorpayCheckout is the name used in cordova

Answer (score 9):

Step 1:

Declare razorPay at where you imported modules.
`declare var Razorpay: any;`

```js
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

declare var Razorpay: any; 

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-checkout',
  templateUrl: './checkout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkout.component.css']
})
```

Step 2:

Add script file checkout.js to index

Step 3:
Add following required function

```js
 payNow( ) { 
        
          var options = {
            "key": "rzp_test_dveDexCQKoGszl",
            "amount":((this.buyNow==1)?this.shared.totalAmountWithDisocuntBuyNow:this.shared.totalAmountWithDisocunt)*100, // 2000 paise = INR 20
            "name": " MARKET",
            "description": "Order #",
           
            "handler": function (response){
                console.log(response);
                alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
 
         
              
               },
            "prefill": {
                "name":  this.shared.orderDetails.billing_firstname + " " + this.shared.orderDetails.billing_lastname,
                "email": this.shared.customerData.customers_email_address,
                "contact": this.shared.customerData.customers_telephone,
           
            },
            "notes": {  },
            "theme": {
                "color": "blue"
            }
        };
        var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);

       rzp1.open();
  
     // body...
   } 
   paid()
   {alert();}
```

Comment: Hey sara ..u've exposed ur api_key..(i've made a transaction as well...)..just a heads up..!

Answer (score 3):

Add anywhere in your component html file:

```
<button  (click)="initPay()">Pay</button>
```

and update your your component.ts file like so:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare var Razorpay: any; 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'client';
    options = {
        "key": 'your app id', // Enter the Key ID generated from the Dashboard
        "amount": "50000", // Amount is in currency subunits. Default currency is INR. Hence, 50000 refers to 50000 paise or INR 500.
        "currency": "INR",
        "name": "Acme Corp",
        "description": "A Wild Sheep Chase is the third novel by Japanese author  Haruki Murakami",
        "image": "https://example.com/your_logo",
        "handler": function (response) {
            alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
        },
        "prefill": {
            "name": "amin uddin",
            "email": "amidenf9701@gmail.com",
            "contact": "7992239847"
        },
        "notes": {
            "address": "note value"
        },
        "theme": {
            "color": "#F37254"
        }
    };
    initPay() {
        var rzp1 = new Razorpay(this.options);
        rzp1.open();
        console.log("works");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working fine in the separate project but it's throwing the error 'Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null' in an existing project. Do you any idea?

Comment: Hi @amin.. after success response i get only... payment id...not order is can you tell me how to get order I'd?

Answer (score 2):

declare **Razorpay** inside **polyfills.ts** file

```
// polyfills.ts file
declare global {
    interface Window {
        Razorpay: any;
    }
 }
```

MyComponent.ts file

```
@Component({...})
class MyComponent {

constructor() {
}
rzp1:any;
options = {
   "key": "rzp_test_HTQz79bVMhpN4L",
   "amount": "2000",
   "name": "Merchant Name",
   ....
   .....
};

public initPay():void {
   this.rzp1 = new window.Razorpay(this.options);
   this.rzp1.open();
}
}
```