# Access json function variable from javascript code to Angular6

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am simply trying to implement Razorpay checkout where, it handles the response for paymentid like this:

```
options = {
    'key': 'rzp_test_xxxxxxxxxx',
    'amount': 0, // 2000 paise = INR 20
    'name': 'JJJJ',
    'description': 'Purchase Description',
    'image': '../../../../assets/img/jiffylogo.png',
    'display_currency': 'USD',
    'display_amount': 0,
    'handler': function (response) {
      return response.razorpay_payment_id;
    },
    'prefill': {
        'name': '',
        'email': ''
    },
    'notes': {
        'address': ''
    },
    'theme': {
        'color': '#AF8AC0'
    }
};
```

Now, I am looking to access `razorpay_payment_id` from Angular function to further send it to server side for the processing like this:

```
const payid = this.rzp1.open();
```

But this isn't returning the paymentid.

I tried different ways to get it done like in function instead of returning, I tried to assign the value to component scoped variable. But that returns undefined due to obvious reason.

This is the original code from Razorpay:

```
<button id="rzp-button1">Pay</button>
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
var options = {
    "key": "YOUR_KEY_ID",
    "amount": "2000", // 2000 paise = INR 20
    "name": "Merchant Name",
    "description": "Purchase Description",
    "image": "/your_logo.png",
    "handler": function (response){
        alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
    },
    "prefill": {
        "name": "Gaurav Kumar",
        "email": "test@test.com"
    },
    "notes": {
        "address": "Hello World"
    },
    "theme": {
        "color": "#F37254"
    }
};
var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);

document.getElementById('rzp-button1').onclick = function(e){
    rzp1.open();
    e.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

Which has been modified for angular purpose like this:

[How to Integrate Razorpay in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43321694/how-to-integrate-razorpay-in-angular-2)

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Elaborate your question and share all related code.

Comment: have edited my question

Comment: Console log for `rzp1` and let me know what it prints ?

Comment: un {_evts: {…}, _defs: {…}, id: "BMre0jyt2sKBOp", get: ƒ, set: ƒ, …}