# not getting response in razorpay payment Integration in Angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular7

I am working on Angular 7 project where I am trying to integrate Razorpay for the payment Integration ,

for that I have Integrated the Razorpay payment gateway , 
but I am not getting response on successful payment and on faliue ,

**How do I check the status of my payment/order?**

I am putting my code below

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

declare var Razorpay: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'PaymentIntegration';
  rzp1: any;


  constructor() {}
  openRazorpayCheckout() {


    const options = {
      key: 'rzp_test_glA246D8rCFOVc',
      amount: 100,
      name: 'Merchant Name',
      description: 'Purchase Description',
      prefill: {
        name: 'Harshil Mathur',
        email: 'harshil@razorpay.com'
      },
      notes: {
        address: 'Hello World'
      },
      theme: {
        color: 'green'
      },
      handler: this.paymentResponseHander.bind(this)
    };

    const rzp = new Razorpay(options);
    rzp.open();
  }
  paymentResponseHander(response) {
   console.log(response.razorpay_payment_id);
   }
}
```

**html**

```
<div>
<button (click)="openRazorpayCheckout()">Pay with Razorpay</button>
</div>
```

Index.html

```
 <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for an suggestion simply call a function in handler part.

```
options={
  ....
  "handler": function (response){
        alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
         (or) 
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    },
 .....
}
```

Once logged in response alert. You will call method like this.

```
options={
      ....
      "handler": this.callResponse(response);
        },
     .....
    }

callResponse(response){
   //handle response here.
       alert(JSON.stringify(response));
}
```

For reference,

[How to Integrate Razorpay in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43321694/how-to-integrate-razorpay-in-angular-2/44481010)

https://docs.razorpay.com/docs/android

Answer (score 0):

```
 var options:any = {
      "key": "rzp_test_a4GV9kUSGHOzY4", 
      "amount":  100
      "currency": "INR",
      "name": "HealthInHands",
      "description": "A Wild Sheep Chase is the third novel by Japanese author Haruki Murakami",
      "image": "assets/img/HIH.png",

      "handler": response => {}
```

When You hit The Razor Pay api successfully then u get a transationID from Razorpay end then your successfully made a payment.your transaction details for testing purpose also in the razorpay website once check it

Comment: Could you please explain your answer?